# How to get data between two field in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

i have a field in table like this,

[image]

i have a code like this,

```
public function get_data_promocode($db) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $this->db->from($db);
        $this->db->where('promo_start >=', date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',strtotime($date)));
        $this->db->where('promo_end <=', date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',strtotime($date)));
        $this->db->where('promo_count IS NULL', null, false);
        $this->db->order_by('promo_id DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

how to display promo data that is still on when the current date is between promo_start and promo_end?

Comment: explain what is wrong with your current implementation, and also look in to why your datetime values are in different formats (that can effect output).

Answer (score 0):

get your promo_start_date and promo_end_date and pass those variables with your method

```
$this->db->where("promo_end >= '" . $promo_start_date . "' AND promo_start <= '" . $promo_end_date . "'")
```